# How to find the unique elements in two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, I have the two arrays in PHP:

```
$arr1 = array(1,3,5);
$arr2 = array(1,4,6);
```

I'd like to create two new arrays, with each containing the elements that are unique to each array. So I would like to get the following two arrays as output:

```
$arr1_uniques = array(3,5);
$arr2_uniques = array(4,6);
```

what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to subtract each array from the other, like so:

```
$arr1_uniques = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
$arr2_uniques = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

Comment: You can actually skip the intersect and just diff directly with the other array. Removing an element that is not present has no impact.

Comment: you do not need to find duplicates as array_diff as declared in manual "Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays."

Comment: Cool, I missed that - obviously I shouldn't answer questions in a language I haven't been actively using for months. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr1_uniques = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
$arr2_uniques = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

http://php.net/array_diff

Comment: orr array_intersect, if you care about assoc keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function to accomplish that problem. You have to use it twice to get results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function. As example:

```
function uniq(array $arr){

$temp_arr = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
    if (in_array($arr[$i], $temp_arr)) {
            continue;
    }

    $temp_arr[] = $arr[$i];

    }

return $temp_arr;
}

print_r(uniq([1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 7, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 0, 12, 123, 1, 4, 7, 66, 77]));

///Output: Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 6
[4] => 7
[5] => 8
[6] => 0
[7] => 12
[8] => 123
[9] => 4
[10] => 66
[11] => 77
)
```

Comment: You could, but given that there's already a built-in function for it, it wouldn't be a very good idea.